# How to revert the media structure from /uploads/year/month to the /uploads directory in wordpress?

Tags: uploads, media, wp-cli

I tried to use wp-cli using regex like this:

```
wp search-replace 'uploads/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/' 'uploads/' --all-tables --regex
```

but in this case there is a problem with possibly repeated file names and overwritting them. Is there a plugin or script that converts directory structures to /uploads including all possible dependencies and cases?